# How do I create a guild in Wildstar?

Tags: wildstar

How does someone create a Guild in Wildstar?

1. What are the requirements?
2. Where do I go?
3. Do I need currency?
4. Do I need people to sign a charter?
5. Any other details?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of now (open beta) guild creation works like this:

1. You need to be at least level 12.
2. A guild registrar NPC in your main city (Thayd or Illium), ask a guard for directions.
3. The cost is 10 gold.
4. No charter signing needed.
5. There is a guild currency called influence, earned by playing together with other guild members. It is used for unlocking different guild perks.